# Frasca's mapping of classical Yang-Mills to $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, yang-mills, classical-field-theory

I recently came across an article on the arXiv [0709.2042](http://arxiv.org/abs/0709.2042) written by Marco Frasca, where he provides a mapping between classical Yang-Mills theory to $\phi^4$ theory.  Has his idea been fruitful in understanding the infrared regime of quantum Yang-Mills theory, as he claims?

Comment: A mathematician named Terry who specializes in analysis argued rather convincing [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory#Removed_.22Integrable_solutions_of_classical_Yang-Mills_equations_and_QFT.22) that the main theorem in Frasca's paper is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for answering for me but this information is just incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

This theorem was corrected in a published paper as asked by Terry Tao (see [here](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S021773230903165X) and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.2357)). Tao conceded that the new version gives a correct theorem and mapping holds in an approximate way (see [here](http://wiki.math.toronto.edu/DispersiveWiki/index.php/Talk%3aYang-Mills_equations)) in the limit of a large coupling that is what one needs in the infrared limit.

Please, before to give incorrect information, just ask the author.

See [this post](http://marcofrasca.wordpress.com/2013/09/21/ending-and-consequences-of-terry-taos-criticism/) in my blog for an in-depth discussion.

Comment: Dear Jon, not to conflict with Phys.SE self-citation policy, please spell out explicitly in your answer if you are in any way associated with the author of the paper arXiv:0709.2042.

Comment: Dear @Qmechanic, Thanks a lot for pointing this out. Yes I am the author. I thought this would have been clear from my profile where there is a link to my blog with a list of my publications. Somewhat involved but nothing to hide.